# Combining Pandas Dataframe with indexed value as column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following two pandas DataFrames:

```
main_table = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A'],
                           [2, 'B'],
                           [3,'C']],
                           columns=['id', 'label'])

extras_table = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'e1', 'e1_Val'], 
                             [1, 'e2', 'e2_Val'],
                             [2, 'e2', 'e2_Val2'],
                             [3, 'e1', 'e1_val3']], 
                             columns=['main_id', 'col_label', 'value'])
```

I want to use the 'main_id' column of extras_table, and 'col_label' to create additional columns on main_table.  i.e.:

```
result:
   id label       e1        e2
0   1     A   e1_Val    e2_Val
1   2     B     None   e2_Val2
2   3     C  e1_val3      None
```

Note that some of the rows may not have all of the new columns.  Is this possible in Pandas, without iterating over extras table, and adding the new columns/values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xdf = extras_table.set_index(['main_id', 'col_label']) \
    .unstack().value.reset_index('main_id')

main_table.merge(xdf, left_on='id', right_on='main_id').drop('main_id', axis=1)
```

[image]